# How to create flow view layout in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7, coverflow

I have successfully implemented the CoverFlowView in my page. However, as you can see in the attached image from SnapGuide, the view does not start from the centre but from the extreme right.

I tried to do the same by making the first view as an Index of 0 having a transparent background. This seem to work fine when I kept scrolling sideways. However, at the time of scrolling backwards the Indexes seemed to override onto one another. Example: Index of 5 would overlap Index of 0. I have no idea why this is happening.

Could there have been an alternate way that SnapGuide would have implemented that I am missing out on?

Comment: Where is the `attached image` ?

Comment: am implementing exactly like tr.pinterest.com/pin/131519251592282007